# How to navigate to a lightning component from quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

I have a custom object named `New/Renewal Tracker` in that object there are many quick actions button what i want to do is clicking on that quick action button, want to change a picklist value e.g if i clicked on draft button picklist value will be draft, if i click on complete button picklist value will be changed to complete

[image]

my problem is when click on complete review button i have called standard record edit page

[image]

when page loads it shows picklist values of record what i want when the page loads it shows value completed as i click on completed button

Comment: I have create a component where that I used lightning record form but when i click on completed review button it redirects to that component it dosent show on same quick action modal

Comment: When you click on custom action, it should update the picklist and show a message in quick action modal that record is updated to 'draft' or other value?

Comment: problem is if u see 2nd screenshot, i clicked on complete review button in picklist status i want to update that to complete (not data base update just want to change field value when that forms load)

Answer (score 1):

The **force:editRecord** does not allow you to pre-define any value other recordid of the record to be update. As a workaround:-

> You can use quick action of type update a record by pre-define a value
>   for the field you are looking for. It will give you the picklist value
>   selected by default when you click on the button. Based on the user
>   interaction with save button, the value will be get saved.

A sample example with step is:-

1. In the object management settings for accounts, go to Buttons,
   Links, and Actions.
2. Click Create a Case.
3. In the Predefined Values related list, click New.
4. From the Field Name drop-down list, select Status.
5. Set its value to New.
6. Click Save.
7. Now we need to remove the Status field from the action layout. On
   the action detail page, click Edit Layout.
8. Click the Status field on the layout and drag it up to the palette.
9. Click Save.

> **Tip** You can remove a required field from the action layout, but make sure that the field has a predefined value. Otherwise, users
>   can’t create records.

Read more here:-

1. [Try It Out: Set a Predefined Field Value on an Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/actions_predef_values_task.htm)
2. [REPLACING URL HACKS WITH PRE-DEFINED ACTIONS IN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/05/28/replacing-url-hacks-with-pre-defined-actions-in-lightning-experience/)